# First Android app: R cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: android

From the [Android Getting Started][1] tutorial I'm trying to build my first app. This however, is quite a process. I was at the point "Add the Actions to the Action Bar" on [this page][2] when I encountered the error *main_activity_actions cannot be resolved or is not a field* for this line:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
```

So I found a similar post here on SO, which suggests to remove `import android.R;` and then do `Project -> Clean` and rebuild. Since I didn't have the `import android.R;` in it I simply tried to add it, do a Clean and rebuild, but this leaves me with even more errors. So I removed the `import android.R;` again and did a Clean and Rebuild again, but now it still gives me all those new errors, saying: `R cannot be resolved to a variable` for the following lines (these lines do not appear close to eachother, but throughout the file):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

For reference, the total file is [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CucguViP).

Can anybody please help me out here? What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

[EDIT]
Below the code in my res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml. If you need to see any more code let me know!

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <!-- Add some other thing, just cuz I can.. -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_something_else"
        android:title="@string/action_something_else"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: If you got this then that means you are doing anything wrong in your .xml file. Check it whether it is ok or not.

Comment: do you have errors in your resource files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your xml or check the res folder folder if there any problem with the image's name . Or check Window/showview/Errorlog

Comment: Awesome, this was it! One png file was misnamed. Finally I saw it also in the errror log. Excuse me for not seeing that before!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the import R file, then try Clean the project, then rebuild, should work.

Comment: If by "rebuild, you mean hitting the "Run" button, I did this. Without success unfortunately.. Any more tips?

Comment: no not the run button, go to Project, uncheck Build Automatically, then click Build Project.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

give your main activity xml file name in `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_main);`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having trouble on this, make sure that the XML file main_activity_actions.xml is in /res/menu/ and NOT in /res/layout

Answer (score 0):

Check your all XML files inside res folder. You may having some error in one of your XML files

Answer (score 0):

Replace "R.menu" to be "R.layout" as below->>

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_actions, menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you put the action_search and action_settings into values/strings.xml, in case they aren't there already.

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="action_search">Search</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

I had the same problem, and I had stupidly not checked to see if action_search was defined. Also, the png referenced in the "android:icon" was missing from the "drawables" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, in my case the name of the xml file was main.xml not `main_activity_actions`. Changing it from `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);` to `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` fixed the problem.